# Problema con sonido en Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

He instalado Lubuntu 17.10 en un portatil antiguo (HP modelo 2133 mini.

El dispositivo de sonido es detectado como VT8237A/VT8251 HDA pero el pc no emite sonido de ningun tipo.

¿Alguna solucion para esto?

Comment: Hola, este foro es para preguntas relacionadas con programación, tienes dos comunidades más adecuadas para resolver tu problema: https://askubuntu.com y https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Recuerda preguntar en ingles, ambos sitios están en ese idioma

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque se refiere a problemas en la instalacion de un sistema operativo